# jurabib: how to delete comma between "lastname" and "firstname" in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, punctuation, jurabib

I use the [`jurabib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/jurabib) package and everything works fine.

Entries in bibliography look like this:

> **Doe**, **John**: How to vote for a Democrat, Kluwer 2012.

Does anyone know how I can delete the comma between "Doe" and "John"?

I found that for the [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) package there is this command:

```
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
```

However, this does not work for `jurabib`.

Comment: Switched to \usepackage{biblatex}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking into `jurabib.sty`, I stumbled upon a suspicious code block with lots of hardcoded comma signs. Replacing them with space commands indeed did the trick. That doesn't mean I know what all those macros do, and it also doesn't mean you shouldn't consider switching to `biblatex`. ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{jurabib}

\renewcommand\jbRevedFirstOnlyLast{\biblnfmt{\jbLast}}%
\renewcommand\jbRevedFirstNoVonNoJr{\biblnfmt{\jbLast\ }\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst}}%
\renewcommand\jbRevedFirstNoVonJr{\biblnfmt{\jbLast\ \jbJunior\ }\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst}}%
\renewcommand\jbRevedFirstVonNoJr{\biblnfmt{\jbLast\ }\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst\space\jbVon}}%
\renewcommand\jbRevedFirstVonJr{\biblnfmt{\jbLast\ \jbJunior\ }\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst\space\jbVon}}%
\renewcommand\jbRevedNotFirstOnlyLast{\biblnfmt{\jbLast}}%
\renewcommand\jbRevedNotFirstNoVonNoJr{\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst\space}\biblnfmt{\jbLast}}%
\renewcommand\jbRevedNotFirstNoVonJr{\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst\space}\biblnfmt{\jbLast\ \jbJunior}}%
\renewcommand\jbRevedNotFirstVonNoJr{\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst\space\jbVon~}\biblnfmt{\jbLast}}%
\renewcommand\jbRevedNotFirstVonJr{\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst\space\jbVon~}\biblnfmt{\jbLast\ \jbJunior}}%
\renewcommand\jbNotRevedOnlyLast{\biblnfmt{\jbLast}}%
\renewcommand\jbNotRevedNoVonNoJr{\biblnfmt{\jbLast\ }\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst}}% <-- THE IMPORTANT CHANGE
\renewcommand\jbNotRevedNoVonJr{\biblnfmt{\jbLast\ \jbJunior\ }\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst}}%
\renewcommand\jbNotRevedVonNoJr{\biblnfmt{\jbLast\ }\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst\space\jbVon}}%
\renewcommand\jbNotRevedVonJr{\biblnfmt{\jbLast\ \jbJunior\ }\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst\space\jbVon}}%

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{jurabib}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks lockstep, I took your advice and switched to Biblatex!