# Getting jurabib to stop turning around the names in the bibliography

Tags: jurabib

As i need to use the footcite option i did a good part of googeling and found out that jurabib suports this just right away. I got everything to work but as it turns out the author name is turned around and as i am qouting from dictionaries as well it looks as ridicoulus as this:

> Britannica, Encyclopedia

I managed to get rid auf the comma by applying what was recommended here: [jurabib: how to delete comma between "lastname" and "firstname" in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81816/jurabib-how-to-delete-comma-between-lastname-and-firstname-in-bibliography)

which resulted in the code looking like that:

```
\usepackage{jurabib}

\jurabibsetup{
    commabeforerest,
    ibidem=strict,
    citefull=first,
    see,
    titleformat={colonsep,all},
}

\renewcommand*{\jbauthorfont}{\textsc}
\renewcommand*{\biblnfont}{\scshape\textbf}
\renewcommand*{\bibfnfont}{\normalfont\textbf}
%Only for removing the comma:
\renewcommand\jbRevedFirstOnlyLast{\biblnfmt{\jbLast}}%
\renewcommand\jbRevedFirstNoVonNoJr{\biblnfmt{\jbLast\ }\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst}}%
\renewcommand\jbRevedFirstNoVonJr{\biblnfmt{\jbLast\ \jbJunior\ }\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst}}%
\renewcommand\jbRevedFirstVonNoJr{\biblnfmt{\jbLast\ }\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst\space\jbVon}}%
\renewcommand\jbRevedFirstVonJr{\biblnfmt{\jbLast\ \jbJunior\ }\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst\space\jbVon}}%
\renewcommand\jbRevedNotFirstOnlyLast{\biblnfmt{\jbLast}}%
\renewcommand\jbRevedNotFirstNoVonNoJr{\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst\space}\biblnfmt{\jbLast}}%
\renewcommand\jbRevedNotFirstNoVonJr{\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst\space}\biblnfmt{\jbLast\ \jbJunior}}%
\renewcommand\jbRevedNotFirstVonNoJr{\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst\space\jbVon~}\biblnfmt{\jbLast}}%
\renewcommand\jbRevedNotFirstVonJr{\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst\space\jbVon~}\biblnfmt{\jbLast\ \jbJunior}}%
\renewcommand\jbNotRevedOnlyLast{\biblnfmt{\jbLast}}%
\renewcommand\jbNotRevedNoVonNoJr{\biblnfmt{\jbLast\ }\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst}}% <-- THE IMPORTANT CHANGE
\renewcommand\jbNotRevedNoVonJr{\biblnfmt{\jbLast\ \jbJunior\ }\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst}}%
\renewcommand\jbNotRevedVonNoJr{\biblnfmt{\jbLast\ }\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst\space\jbVon}}%
\renewcommand\jbNotRevedVonJr{\biblnfmt{\jbLast\ \jbJunior\ }\bibfnfmt{\jbCheckedFirst\space\jbVon}}%
```

And the following reslut:

> Britannica Encyclopedia

Does anybody know how to get the wished result?

It would look something like this:

> Encyclopedia Britannica

```
\bibliography{literature/library}
\bibliographystyle{jurabib}
```

Comment: Are you only concerned about names like this?  I assume for real names you want the Lastname, First name format, right?  If so, this is a duplicate of [Using a 'corporate author' in the “author” field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/2693)

Comment: yes that's right. sorry i didn't find it and thanks for the help